# Autowiring in Spring Batch returning null

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to autowire one of the configuration class but it is returning null. Can you please help me to figure out what I am doing wrong?

The configuration class looks like below -

```
package com.xyz.abc.mn.filereader.batch.config;
@Configuration
public class Xyz{

@Value("${property1:#{'09'}}")
private String property1;
...
...
//getters and setters
```

This is the Util class where I am trying to use the autowire -

```
package com.xyz.abc.mn.filereader.batch.util;
public class XyzUtil{

@Autowired
private Xyz xyz;

public boolean method1(){
     xyz.getProperty1();  //Giving Null pointer exception as xyz is Null
     ...
     ...
```

My application class looks like below -

```
package com.xyz.abc.mn.filereader.batch.config;
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.xyz.abc.mn.filereader.batch.*""})
@PropertySource(value="file:${props.file}") 

public class MainApplication {

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Spring Batch, it is due to a misconfiguration of Spring beans. [@Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) indicates that a class declares one or more `@Bean` definition methods. This is not the case for your `Xyz`. You should annotate it with `@Component`.

Moreover, `XyzUtil` is not managed by Spring, that's why dependency injection is not performed in that class. You need to annotate it with `@Component` as well.

Comment: Actually I already tried that, it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: It should. Please provide a minimal complete example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or check duplicate questions.